# How to filter results in a pandas dataframe, based on the values in other columns of the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following information.

[image]

I need to filter the dataframe based on the condition - if 'dob' is greater than 'justdate' and less than 'testdate'. So, the resultant dataframe will only have one row which is - [1, naomi, jang, 27, 10-19-1992, 04-05-1990, 04-05-2016] as it falls between the two dates i.e.., 'justdate' and 'testdate'.

The code that I'm trying to use:

```
filter1 = my_df.loc[my_df['dob'] > my_df['justdate']]
filter2 = my_df.loc[my_df['dob'] < my_df['testdate']]

my_df.where(filter1 & filter2, inplace = True)
```

But, I'm getting the error - "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'"

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = my_df[my_df['dob'].between(my_df['justdate'], my_df['testdate'], inclusive=False)]
```

Your solution is possible change by chain both conditions and filter by `boolean indexing`:

```
df = my_df[(my_df['dob'] > my_df['justdate']) & (my_df['dob'] < my_df['testdate'])]
```

Comment: Hello @jezrael! I appreciate your prompt response. Your first solution worked! :) However, the second solution is not working, it is returning an empty dataframe. Just letting you know. Thanks again!